# Do we use prepositions such as "to/towards/along/into..." with the verb "wiggle" as in "the worm wiggled into the hole"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

We can use prepositions such as "**to/towards/along/into...**" with some "**forward/backward movement**" verbs such as walk, go, run, waddle, etc.

For example, the duck waddled along the road.

But we don't use these prepositions with verbs that are not moving backward or forward such as stand. So, we can not say "**he stood into my house**"

There are movement verbs such as wiggle, rock, jiggle etc but they seem to move in one place, not moving forward or backward.

**Can we say?**

*The boat rocked all the way to the mountain.*

*The worm wiggled into the hole.*

*She jiggled from home to school*

Comment: Typo?  "**from to** the mountain"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all fine because the wiggling, rocking or jiggling is combined with forward motion.

"She jiggled from home to school", means that she went from home to school and jiggled as she went. That is slightly odd, but "the car jiggled" would be okay.